# python における ruby の ri 相当のコマンドはありますか？

Tags: python

ruby においては、(整備されているならば)クラスやメソッドのドキュメントを `ri` コマンドで、コマンドライン上から参照できます。

python における、 ruby の `ri` 相当のコマンドはありますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pydocコマンド](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/library/pydoc.html)があります。

```
$ pydoc sys
```

としてその場でドキュメントを表示したり、

```
$ pydoc -p 1234
```

としてドキュメント閲覧用のHTTPサーバーを実行したりします。Python3なら `pydoc3` といったように、Pythonのバージョン毎にコマンドが用意されていると思います。

Answer (score 3):

help関数で行けました。下記はコマンドラインにてeval関数のヘルプを得る場合。

```
python -c help(eval)
```

またipythonと呼ばれるインタープリタでは、eval?でdocument表示できます。
また??を後ろにつけることでソースコードも表示できますが、evalはCで実装された組込み関数なのでソースは見れません。(pythonで実装されているとソースが見れます。)